# Shortcut to switch between fullscreen and non-full screen window of the same app [MacOS]

Tags: macos, osx-spaces

What is the keyboard shortcut to switch between two windows of the same app, when one is in full screen and the other is not?

Answer (score 0):

In the process of writing this question, I figured out the answer is Ctrl + Left Arrow Key or Ctrl + Right Arrow Key

Comment: This is kind of 'half right'. It works when the Spaces are consecutive, but not otherwise. As Fullscreen Spaces have no numbers & cannot be accessed directly by key command like the 'ordinary' numbered Spaces, it becomes a fairly random chance as to whether this works or not.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked before in the [Apple StackExchange.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/188107/how-to-switch-between-multiple-fullscreen-windows-of-same-application-in-os-x) Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to be possible.

[@Marc](https://superuser.com/users/130301/marc) posted a few workarounds on that post in his answer.